# datagrid view select row is not working

Tags: c#, gridview

I filled my gridview cell by cell without using datasource.
when I reload one column after drag and drop some rows, this is not working:

```
row[6].Selected = true;
```

[image: ]]

and just turns the color of the row to blue for selected thing, so when I call if any row was selected it returns me null! and that's because of a sign in default column in gridview which is like pointer to each row. and then when I click on the row for selecting row manually it shows up again.

So now **my question is how to enable that sign for selecting process**.

[image: 6]

Answer (score 0):

The datagridview can actually have multiple selected rows, if the multiselect option is set to true.

The black arrow actually represents the row which has the current cell selected.

So you need to set

```
this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell = this.dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[0];
```

for the row and cell you want highlighted with the black arrow.

Also be aware that the cell you use must be visible, enabled and not a header cell otherwise this might not work.